# SUMIFS + INDEX MATCH com matches repetidos

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho essa tabela com Tecs repetidas (coluna A), relacionadas a produtos diferentes; Preciso somar o total da semana (de 19/4 a 24/4).. estou usando a fórmula abaixo, mas ela só soma o equivalente à primeira linha que encontra da tec gato (linha 3). Como faço para que some o volume referente a todas as tecs GATO?

=SUMIFS(INDEX(D:I;MATCH("Gato";A:A;0);0);D1:I1;"<="&"P4W4";D1:I1;">="&"P4W4")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a seguinte fórmula, onde K2 é a Tec, L2 a data de início e M2 a data de Fim.

`=SUMPRODUCT(D3:I7*(A3:A7=K2)*(D2:I2>=L2)*(D2:I2<=M2))`.